# Asking what the subject complement refers to

Tags: grammar, sentence

I encountered something similar to the following in a reading comprehension exam (not one that I did myself).

> Pepsi is a good example of a soft drink that has a lot of sugar and is therefore unhealthy to drink in large amounts. Coke is another example.
>
> Question - What do the words "another example" refer to?

I think the question is wrong and should NOT be asked, and I'll explain why:
In this case the sentence is composed of a subject (Coke), a linking verb (is) and a subject complement (another example). The words "another example", in this case, being a subject complement, describe the subject (Coke) and they replace a longer description which would be "another example of a soft drink that has a lot of sugar and is therefore unhealthy to drink in large amounts".

In my opinion, asking what the words refer to is misleading and not a legitimate question. Do they "refer to" the subject of the sentence, or do they "refer to" the longer description that they are replacing?
I'd love to hear a more educated opinion on this from an expert.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it. The complement of "example" is omitted, though clearly understood to be "of a soft drink ..."

Comment: But is the question "what do the words 'another example' refer to" clear enough? How does one know whether the question is asking "what is the subject" or "what is the complement"
I'm saying that "refer to" is too ambiguous...
Maybe my question isn't clear enough?

Comment: Deciding on whether everyday or precise grammatical senses apply to a word in a given context often ends in a lack of consensus. 'What is the referent of X?' and 'What does X refer to?@ are clearly in different registers, and arguably have different default interpretations. Arguably. Here, I'd take the everyday sense of 'refer to' and put 'another example' = 'another example [of a soft drink that has a lot of sugar and is therefore unhealthy to drink in large amounts]'. P is one [good] example [of ...]; C is another [good??] example [of ...].

Comment: I get your point and it's fair enough. This is a specifying sense of BE, and the question is ambiguous, because the answer could well be *coke*, because *coke* and *an example* both refer to the same drink. What they want to know is what coke is an example ***of***. In other words they want to know what *other* phrase *an example* co-refers with. And what they are really testing here is how you interpret the ellipsis of the PP complement of the noun *example*. Many students will guess this, but only because *coke* is too easy or, contrastively, because it doesn't have the word *example* in it.

Comment: A good dollop of common sense tells us that in full it's "Coke is another example of a soft drink that ..."

Comment: Thank you, great answers! Especially "@Araucaria-Nothereanymore.", who broke it down into details. Too bad I can't score these comments :-)